# Looping on FolderIterator and FileIterator - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm making a script to loop in a Google Drive folder and noticed I don't know what's the best way to loop over iterators (specifically FolderIterator and FileIterator).
My first approach

```js
const drive_id  = '__________';
let base_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(drive_id),
    sub_folders = base_folder.getFolders();
Logger.log(base_folder.getFolders());
for(let sub_folder of sub_folders) 
{
    Logger.log(sub_folder);
}
```

outputs `Error  TypeError: sub_folders is not iterable`.

Secondly I tried with while loops and checks on hasNext(), but I didn't find them beautifyl enough. I'm currently set with this for loop, that works and is clean enough but still looks a bit hacky.

```js
/*...*/
for(let sub_folders = base_folder.getFolders(); sub_folders.hasNext();)
{
  let sub_folder = sub_folders.next();
  Logger.log(sub_folder);
}
```

Also notice how I couldn't declare `sub_folder` within the loop itself. So, what's the proper way of doing it?

Also, what if I wanted to use a `map` or `filter` on the `sub_folders` instead?

*Note: this question is probably of broader scope than google-script, but I couldn't find the right terminology to ask the question differently so I preferred to stick to the particular case I found.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's the proper way of looping a FolderIterator or FileIterator?

- The proper way of doing it by using a `while` loop.
- The reason for that has to do with the [hasNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#hasNext()) function which returns a `Boolean` (`true` or `false`) and the only loop that natively works with booleans is the `while` loop.

### Also, what if I wanted to use a map or filter on the sub_folders instead?

- In your code `sub_folder` is an object of type [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder). Unfortunately, you can only retrieve the folders one by one within the `while` loop by using [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next()) so you can't directly apply `map` or `filter` on the [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator).
- Instead, you can create an array of folders by pushing each folder to an array (within the `while` loop) and then use `map`.

**Example:**

This script finds all the folders and store them in an array and then uses [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to [get the name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getName()) of each sub folder:

```
function myFunction() {
  const base_folder  = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder_id');
  const sub_folders  = base_folder.getFolders();
  const folders = [];

  while (sub_folders.hasNext()){
    let folder = sub_folders.next()
    folders.push(folder);
  }
  
  const folder_names = folders.map(f=>f.getName());
  console.log(folder_names);
}
```

Here is a list of all the available methods you can apply to each element of the `folders` array: [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)

Comment: Clear enough, thanks. may I ask if there's any reason to **avoid** for loops in this situation? The main pro I see is saving one line by having the declaration inside `for(const sub_folders=base_folder.getFolders(); sub_folders.hasNext(); )`, but upon testing I also see the iterator gets destroyed after getting used, which may be desirable in some cases

Comment: @ABO Glad the answer was helpful to you. The iteration stops when all of the folders/files have been iterated. The same holds true for the `while` loop so it is not a particular advantage for `for` loop. I tested your alternative approach and it works. I mentioned that `while` is the proper way do to it because 1) it is used in the official documentation for these tasks 2) you achieve the same in less code. But since `for` loop works as well feel free to use it. Also consider accepting the answer if it solved your original question.